# Load Content of HTML scripts

Tags: html, caching, browser, web, src

Hello Good Day Everyone!

Will this work? or is there a better alternative? that may not require us to redo the 2nd page...

Comment: Don't do this. Leave prescient loading to the browser. By all means include all CSS and Javascript in one file and load it on the home page, but you don't need iframes for that.

Comment: This could work. However, it sounds extremely unreliable. Have you considered removing the `iframes` using `ajax` to load the new content onto the page?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Leave prescient loading to the browser. By all means include all CSS and Javascript in one file and load it on the home page, but you don't need iframes for that.

Do proper optimization instead like everyone else. Look into how to [optimize CSS and JS loading.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090017/optimizing-javascript-and-css-requests) Consider [minifying your CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787789/any-recommendations-for-a-css-minifier) and JS. Use tools like [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) to find bottlenecks in your page delivery.